# Intellij refactoring bulk move sometimes only moves one item

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm attempting to refactor some python code using intellij 2017.2.1 running on win7 with the python plugin.  Specifically I'm moving some functions from one file to another in the same package.  If I select refactor/move and select one item this is successful.  If I select more than one item (in the bulk list in the move dialog) only one item is moved.  I can see multiple items have been selected to move in the preview.
If I set up a dumb test case bulk move works but for my (no doubt tangled code) it fails.  There is no error.  Is refactoring checking some 'validity measure' of the bulk move but not telling me why it can't move more than one item?

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24365.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it thanks.  Nice to know I'm not alone!.